# How to fix import error from open fermion?

Tags: python

I'm trying to run this [example](https://github.com/quantumlib/OpenFermion-Psi4/blob/master/examples/openfermionpsi4_demo.ipynb) in a terminal. When I run it I get the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openfermion.chem'
```

I'm running in a conda environment with python 3.6 and openfermion installed, `pip show openfermion` shows

```
Name: openfermion
Version: 0.11.0
Summary: The electronic structure package for quantum computers.
Home-page: http://www.openfermion.org
Author: The OpenFermion Developers
Author-email: help@openfermion.org
License: Apache 2
Location: /home/al/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: requests, scipy, pubchempy, networkx, h5py, numpy
Required-by: openfermionpsi4
```

Comment: Kindly specify how did you install openfermion on your machine

Comment: @Ashraf I installed with `pip install openfermion`

Answer (score 0):

Install openfermion using `conda` rather than `pip` by running these lines in your terminal

```sh
conda install -c psi4 openfermion
conda install -c psi4/label/dev openfermion
```

Comment: I did this and now my installed openfermion version is 0.9.0, but I still get the same ModuleNotFoundError

Comment: try and restart conda

Comment: Not sure how to restart conda, I restarted my computer and I get the same error.

Comment: could you please show me the output of `pip -V` @mTesseracted

Comment: `pip 20.2.4 from /home/al/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)`, also I just tried installing directly from the repo and it now works in interactive python but not when I run the script.

Comment: the error is now from within Psi4, when I installed from the repo I must have broken its dependencies

Comment: Seems to be a bit of confliction happened on your system,

1) Open fresh terminal
2) Type: `conda config --add channels http://conda.anaconda.org/psi4`
3) Then: `python -m conda install psi4`
4) `git clone https://github.com/quantumlib/OpenFermion-Psi4`
5) `cd OpenFermion-Psi4`
6) `python -m pip install --user openfermionpsi4`

Comment: For psi4 it said already installed. For openfermion-psi4 do you mean `python -m pip install -e .` after the `cd` into the cloned repo? Other wise it's just going to install from the internet. Either way I tried both and it doesn't work. When I install openfermion with pip it can't find `openfermion.chem`, but when I install it by cloning and doing `python -m pip install -e .` I can then successfully do `from openfermion.chem import MolecularData`, but then it breaks openfermion-psi4 dependencies...